# Scala pattern matching with disjunctions not working

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala and don't understand why the following is not working.

I want to refactor a (tested) `mergeAndCount` function which is part of a counting inversions algorithm to utilize pattern matching. Here is the unrefactored method:

```
def mergeAndCount(b: Vector[Int], c: Vector[Int]): (Int, Vector[Int]) = {
  if (b.isEmpty && c.isEmpty)
    (0, Vector())
  else if (!b.isEmpty && (c.isEmpty || b.head < c.head)) {
    val (count, r) = mergeAndCount(b drop 1, c)
    (count, b.head +: r)
  } else {
    val (count, r) = mergeAndCount(b, c drop 1)
    (count + b.length, c.head +: r)
  }
}
```

Here is my refactored method `mergeAndCount2`. Which is working fine.

```
def mergeAndCount2(b: Vector[Int], c: Vector[Int]): (Int, Vector[Int]) = (b, c) match {
  case (Vector(), Vector()) =>
    (0, Vector())
  case (bh +: br, Vector()) =>
    val (count, r) = mergeAndCount2(br, c)
    (count, bh +: r)
  case (bh +: br, ch +: cr) if bh < ch =>
    val (count, r) = mergeAndCount2(br, c)
    (count, bh +: r)
  case (_, ch +: cr) =>
    val (count, r) = mergeAndCount2(b, cr)
    (count + b.length, ch +: r)
}
```

However as you can see the second and third case are duplicate code. I therefore wanted to combine them using the disjunction like this:

```
  case (bh +: br, Vector()) | (bh +: br, ch +: cr) if bh < ch =>       
    val (count, r) = mergeAndCount2(br, c)
    (count, bh +: r)
```

This gives me an error though (on the case line): `illegal variable in pattern alternative`.

What am I doing wrong?

Any help (also on style) is greatly appreciated.

**Update**: thanks to your suggestions here is my result:

```
@tailrec
def mergeAndCount3(b: Vector[Int], c: Vector[Int], acc : (Int, Vector[Int])): (Int, Vector[Int]) = (b, c) match {
  case (Vector(), Vector())  =>
    acc
  case (bh +: br, _) if c.isEmpty ||  bh < c.head =>
    mergeAndCount3(br, c, (acc._1, acc._2 :+ bh))
  case (_, ch +: cr) =>
    mergeAndCount3(b, cr, (acc._1 + b.length, acc._2 :+ ch))
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When pattern matching with pipe (|) you are not allowed to bind any variable other than wildcard (_).

This is easy to understand: in the body of your `case`, what would be the actual type of `bh` or `br` for example if your two alternatives match different types?

Edit - from the scala reference:

> 8.1.11 Pattern Alternatives Syntax: Pattern ::= Pattern1 { ‘|’ Pattern1 } A pattern alternative p 1 | . . . | p n consists of a
>   number of alternative patterns p i . All alternative patterns are type
>   checked with the expected type of the pattern. They may no bind
>   variables other than wildcards. The alternative pattern matches a
>   value v if at least one its alternatives matches v.

Edit after first comment - you can use the wildcard to match something like this for example:

```
try {
 ...
} catch {
  case (_: NullPointerException | _: IllegalArgumentException) => ...
}
```

Comment: Ahh, I actually read this text, but misunderstood. No variable bindings are allowed at all. The wildcard bit confused me.

Answer (score 3):

If you think about that, looking at your case clause, how should the compiler know if in the case body it should be allowed to use *ch* and *cr* or not?

This sort of questions make it very hard to make the compiler support disjunction and variable binding in the same case clause, thus this is not allowed at all.

Your mergeAndCount2 function looks quite fine with respect to pattern matching. I think that its most evident problem is not being tail-recursive and thus not running in constant stack space. If you can solve this problem you will probably end with something that is less repetitive as well.

Comment: Yes,  of course, understood and thanks. Refactoring to tail recursion was my next step.

Answer (score 2):

You can rewrite the case expression and move the disjunction to the `if` part

```
case (bh +: br, cr) if cr.isEmpty || bh < cr.head =>
  val (count, r) = mergeAndCount2(br, c)
  (count, bh +: r)
```

**Update:**

You can yet simplify a little bit:

```
@tailrec
def mergeAndCount3(b: Vector[Int], c: Vector[Int],
    count: Int = 0, r: Vector[Int] = Vector()): (Int, Vector[Int]) = 
  (b, c) match {
    case (bh +: br, _) if c.isEmpty || bh < c.head =>
      mergeAndCount3(br, c, count, bh +: r)
    case (_, ch +: cr) =>
      mergeAndCount3(b, cr, count + b.length, ch +: r)
    case _ => (count, r)
  }
```